# How to print hive beeline output without header and non tabular form

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

I want to print this output

```
+------------------------------------------------+--+
|                    tab_name                    |
+------------------------------------------------+--+
| table1                                         |
| table2                                         |
| table3                                         |
| wt                                             |
| wa                                             |
| wal                                            |
+------------------------------------------------+--+
```

AS
without header and without table format in beeline

table1
 table2 
 table3 
 wt
 wa
 wal

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the shell

```
beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 -e "select ..."
```

Within beeline

```
!set showheader false
!set outputformat tsv2    
select ...;
```